# Find first occurence of specified element in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-search

lets say i have an array `A` in non-descending order like this

```
A = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 500, 600]
```

My question is: how to find the first occurence (index) of an element equal or greather (if 4 is not present) than 4?

O(n) solution is easy, i would like to have something faster.
Probably binary search, but have no idea how to modify it.

Comment: This is a classic [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Comment: Binary search is the answer. O(lg(n))

Comment: @amit But there might be many occurences of 4, BS would only tell me random index

Comment: @jpos you can move to the left then :)

Comment: @AdamSkywalker and what if 4 doesn't exists and i want 5?

Comment: @jpos Find something smaller and move right

Comment: @jpos Binary search perfectly handles that case. For example [java's binary search](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)) return the next higher element if the element does not exist. Getting the leftest element if there are duplicates is simply searching for `x-epsilon`, where `x` is the requested element, and `epsilon` is a small enough value such that there is no element in `[x-epsilon,x)`

Comment: @amit I dont get the second part - how to get leftest(? is it a correct word :D?) element. I can have an array where half values are duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slightly modified binary search to compare with the previous element before returning. If there is a duplicate, you continue the binary search as expected, not serial search, so it's O(log(n)) independently on the structure of the sorted array (e.g. when many duplicates exist). It is written in Java.

*If the element does not present, I return the index of the next greater element, i.e. the index the key should be inserted if I had to put it in the array. I return a negative value as an indicator of "not found".

*The only exception for *negative not-found value* is when the key is the smallest and not-found, where you expect 0 (it doesn't have a negative). But, you can easily handle this special case to distinguish between found and not-found: e.g return the `Integer.MIN_VALUE` or `-(array.length + 1)` if `-lo == 0`.

*If the key is bigger than every array-value, you expect to return an index equal to array size (negative value again).

```
public static int indexOf(int[] a, int key) {
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = a.length - 1;
    while (lo <= hi) {
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        if      (key < a[mid]) hi = mid - 1;
        else if (key > a[mid]) lo = mid + 1;
        else if (mid == 0 || key != a[mid-1]) return mid;
        else hi = mid - 1; //we have a duplicate, go left
    }
    //not present; show index of next greater element
    //OR array.length if bigger than every existing element
    return -lo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what i was looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

Standard binary search:

```
left limit = left end of array
right limit = right end of array
look at middle
if middle == target: stop
else:
    set left or right to middle based on result of comparison
    loop
```

This variation, changes marked with `*`:

```
left limit = left end of array
right limit = right end of array
look at middle
* if limits are close together: stop
* if middle == target and limits are not close together:
*    set right to middle
*    loop
else:
    set left or right to middle based on result of comparison
    loop
```

This will zero in on the leftmost incidence of target, or the point
where target would go if it’s missing. Then just look around in that
area to see what to return.

Answer (score 1):

The following python code uses a simple binary search algorithm to find the upper value. Runtime O(log(n))

```
def binary_search(array, target):
lower = 0
upper = len(array)
while lower < upper:
    x = lower + (upper - lower) // 2
    val = array[x]
    if target == val:
        return x
    elif target > val:
        if lower == x:
            break
        lower = x
    elif target < val:
        upper = x
return upper

# Test Array
arr = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8]
print arr[binary_search(arr, 5)]
```